# How to use axios response error.config to retry the request?

Tags: axios, fetch

I'm following a tutorial that uses an interceptor to retry a request with an authorization token, the code is like this:

```js
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8000/api/";

axios.interceptors.response.use(resp => resp, async error => {
    console.log('error', error)
    if (error.response?.status === 401) {
        const {data, status} = await axios.post('refresh', {}, {withCredentials: true});
        if (status === 200) {
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${data.accessToken}`
        }
        return axios(error.config) ;
    }


    return error;
});
```

In the tutorial this seems to work fine, but in my machine I'm getting this error :

```
error DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'function(header, parser) {
    header = normalizeHeader(header);
    if (!header)
      return void 0;
    const key = findKey(this, header);
    if (key) {
      const value = this[key];
      if (!parser) {
        return value;
      }
      if (parser === true) {
        return parseTokens(value);
      }
      if (utils_default.isFunction(parser)) {
        return parser.call(this, value, key);
      }
      if (utils_default.isRegExp(parser)) {
        return parser.exec(value);
      }
      throw new TypeError("parser must be boolean|regexp|function");
    }
  }' is not a valid HTTP header field value.
    at setRequestHeader (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=1ea4ef45:1208:17)
    at Object.forEach (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=1ea4ef45:89:10)
    at dispatchXhrRequest (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=1ea4ef45:1207:21)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at xhrAdapter (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=1ea4ef45:1111:10)
    at Axios.dispatchRequest (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=1ea4ef45:1424:10)
    at Axios.request (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=1ea4ef45:1666:33)
    at wrap (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=1ea4ef45:16:15)
    at http://localhost:5173/src/intereceptors/axios.ts?t=1665639283918:10:12
    at async http://localhost:5173/src/pages/Home.svelte:74:20
```

if I replace `return axios(error.config);` with a regular request then everything works :

```js
 const userdata  = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/user')
 return userdata;
```

I'm wondering if since I'm using a newer version of axios, things have changed and now this doesn't work anymore, or is there a way to make it work with `axios(error.config)`

Comment: Axios v1.x has too many bugs at this time. Make sure you're using v0.27.2. See https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5089